# Using System.Attribute as Route Attribute Reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection

I have attribute list but I want to get specific properties of each attribute. For examle I have action like

```
[HttpGet, Route("/autocomplete")]
[ActionInfo(Description = "bla bla bla blac")]
// GET: AutoComplete
public ActionResult AutoComplete()
{
    return View();
 }


 private static IEnumerable<Attribute> MyMethod(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes)
 {
    foreach (Attribute attribute in attributes)
    {
        switch (attribute.GetType().Name)
        {
            case "HttpGetAttribute":
            {
                using (attribute as HttpGetAttribute)
                {
                    // my business
                }
                break;
            }
            case "RouteAttribute":
            {
                using (attribute as RouteAttribute)
                {
                    // my business
                }
                break;
            }
            case "ActionInfoAttribute":
            {
                using (attribute as ActionInfoAttribute)
                {
                    // my business
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
private static IEnumerable<Attribute> MyMethod(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes)
{
    foreach (Attribute attribute in attributes)
    {
        if (attribute is HttpGetAttribute)
        {
            // cast to HttpGetAttribute to get properties
        }
        else if (attribute is RouteAttribute)
        {
            // cast to RouteAttribute to get properties
        }
        else if (attribute is ActionInfoAttribute)
        {
            // cast to ActionInfoAttribute to get properties
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

The `using` keyword does not make sense in this context.  `using` is used with types that implement `IDisposable` to dispose of them at the end of the `using` block.

Comment: Worth mentioning c# 7's `if (attribute is HttpGetAttribute casted)`